# PostgreSQL HashAggregate lack of performance

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I have this pretty simple query on a large *foreign (columnstore)* table:

```
select distinct "Business Unit", "Application", "Application Suite", "Account Name" 
    from __tmp_l1_11259 
    where "Date" between '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-31';
```

So, I launch this query in SQL Server using hint `hash group` and it performs  **in less than two seconds**. PostgreSQL goes two ways: it uses HashAggregate or it groups rows by sorting them and perfroming Unique. Here's plans:

```
                                                                    QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=2169041.54..2169041.55 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=11671.983..11672.065 rows=407 loops=1)
  Group Key: "Business Unit", "Application", "Application Suite", "Account Name"
  ->  Foreign Scan on tmp_l1_  (cost=0.00..2164695.79 rows=434575 width=128) (actual time=6.576..4830.866 rows=14237546 loops=1)
        Filter: (("Date" >= '2017-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("Date" <= '2017-10-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 8702454
        CStore File: /datadrive/postgresql/cstore_fdw/16507/16540
        CStore File Size: 87457953966
 Planning time: 15.914 ms
 Execution time: 11672.927 ms
(9 rows)

                                                                    QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=2261840.10..2267272.29 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=44412.373..57237.559 rows=407 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=2261840.10..2262926.54 rows=434575 width=128) (actual time=44412.371..53115.637 rows=14237546 loops=1)
         Sort Key: "Business Unit", "Application", "Application Suite", "Account Name"
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 804440kB
         ->  Foreign Scan on tmp_l1_  (cost=0.00..2164695.79 rows=434575 width=128) (actual time=6.209..5488.539 rows=14237546 loops=1)
               Filter: (("Date" >= '2017-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("Date" <= '2017-10-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 8702454
               CStore File: /datadrive/postgresql/cstore_fdw/16507/16540
               CStore File Size: 87457953966
 Planning time: 19.011 ms
 Execution time: 76676.073 ms
(11 rows)
```

Can I improve perfromance of this query without changing algorithm of HashAggregate in PostgreSQL sources? If yes, how?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: The second one suffers from an under-sized `work_mem`. The external merge is the main contributor for the runtime. Did you try an index on `"Date"`?

Comment: I'm using `PostgreSQL 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit`

Comment: the second one was simulated using `set enable_hashagg to off;`

Comment: What happens when you use a regular table rather than the CStore extensions?

Comment: hm... I cannot create an index because i'm using foreign table.

Comment: When I use an usual table the query just hangs out for a really long time :(

Comment: A query like that on a table with roughly 22 million rows should take that long.

Comment: But by using columstore table and hash grouping in SQL Server that query takes only ~2 seconds. By the way, I have `86 915 096` rows in this table.

Comment: So do I need to modify *(simplify?)* hash grouping method to make it more efficient and fast?

Comment: If the query on a "regular table" never finishes then there is something wrong with your setup. This is what I get on a 80 million row with (what I think is) similar data as yours: https://explain.depesz.com/s/cU0q and adding an index results in: https://explain.depesz.com/s/TwuJ

Answer (score 0):

if you could order the data by date column when you are inserting data, your query could work faster due to use of skip indices.